# Hey guys, anyone use Auto-Rig pro

Tags: rigging

I need something to rig a hand, just a hand not a whole arm, so I found this tool, but I am not sure if it could rig just the hand for me, or it only works for full body meshes. Anyone knows how to use it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Rigify: add an human metarig, delete in edit mode all bones except arm, forearm, hand, fingers.

Then set all bones in the appropriate location.

Back in object mode click the create rig button, hide the metarig, in edit mode enable all bone layers and select and delete all bones relative to arm and forearm.

A couple of little bones are unselectable, so you'll have to toggle the selectability arrow in the outliner and toggle their selectability property.

You can also delete root bone, if unnecessary.

[image]

Comment: From what I've read in the ARP documention, it is not recommended that you ever delete bones generated with Auto Rig Pro. It's said that it will break the addon's code. Instead, you're expected to disable any bones you don't need, and there is a way to do that while in the Reference Bone editing phase. Now, granted, it would seem a strange workflow to generate a whole body rig just to disable everything but the bones of one hand, but I'm guessing that could be done.

Comment: I just created an Auto Rig Pro chat room. Let me know if you would like to discuss things related to it there.

Comment: @ R-800, I would like too.

Comment: where is the chat related to auto rig pro? I would like to join to learn more and share my experience in unity with this feature.